# SparkContext.addFile upload the file to driver node but not workers

Tags: apache-spark, filenotfoundexception

I tried to run a `sc.texfile("file:///.../myLocalFile.txt")` on a cluster and I got `java.io.FileNotFoundException` on the workers.

So I googled and I found `sc.addFile` / `SparkFiles.get` to upload the file to each workers.

So here is my code:

```scala
sc.addFile("file:///.../myLocalFile.txt")
val input = sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get("myLocalFile.txt"))
```

I see that the driver node upload the file to a directory in `/tmp` and then my workers get the `FileNotFoundException` because:

1. I don't see any printout saying that the workers have downloaded the file as they should have
2. They try to access the file with the drivers's path. So I assume `SparkFiles.get()` is ran on the driver node, not the worker (which I confirmed by adding a `println`).

I tried with `spark-submit --files` option and I see exactly the same problem.

So what am I doing wrong? All I want is to `sc.textFile()` on a cluster.

Comment: passing full path of file will help and see this link https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/38482/loading-local-file-to-apache-spark.html

Comment: Giving the full path does not help and I've already been through the link you provide but nothing helps as none of `--files` or `addFiles` work for me (hence my question).

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you find any answers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy files on workers to the same path as on driver, or use hdfs as it will be available on on workers. Workers don't have these files you can go to the folder and see yourself, i would scp them

Comment: Yes but it is precisely to avoid using scp that I wanted to use addFile.
"Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark job on every node." (from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html)

Answer (score 0):

sc.addFile is not for this purpose. If you want to read files through sc, you need put your file on hdfs instead of using sc.addFile

Comment: Ok, but what's the purpose of addFile then? I removed the call to `sc.textFile` (which obviously removes the `FileNotFoundException`) but I still don't see the file uploaded to the workers.